# Looping mp4 in Flash

Tags: flash

I would like to loop a mp4 I embedded using actionscript 3. I've tried using:

```
fvp.source=yourvideo
fvp.autoRewind=true
fvp.addEventListener(VideoEvent.AUTO_REWOUND, videoPlayAgain, false, 0, true)
function videoPlayAgain( event:VideoEvent):void
{
 event.target.play()
}
```

and

```
import fl.video.*;
myFLV.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, rewind);
function rewind(eventObject:VideoEvent):void {
myFLV.autoRewind = true;
myFLV.play();
}
```

But none of it works. I get errors every time, and honestly I hardly know where to put it or what to do with it (I did change the instance name to "yourvideo" and "myFLV"...). Could someone help me out, perhaps?

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665014/as3-how-to-know-if-a-video-has-ended

Answer (score 0):

```
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
import fl.video.VideoEvent;
mcV2.autoRewind = true;
mcV2.autoPlay = true;
function Loop(event:fl.video.VideoEvent):void {
    mcV2.play();
}
mcV2.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.AUTO_REWOUND, Loop);
```

This worked for me. Instead of importing:

```
import fl.video.*;
```

use this:

```
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
import fl.video.VideoEvent;
```

Why these video classes are not being imported with this?

```
import fl.video.*;
```

Doesn't make too much sense.